# Bootstrap Twitter typeahead shows not every item

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-typeahead

i get a json (with page title + url) from a REST

My problem is the dropdown shows only items which include the word i search for (e.g. i search "`google`", my REST gives me a json with e.g. "`google`" and "`g-mail`" but the dropdown shows only "`google`")

When i `alert()` the matches-variable i get e.g. "`google`" and "`g-mail`" (so the json is correct!)

```
$(function(){

    var obj = {};
    var matches = [];

    $(".typeahead").typeahead({
        source: function ( str, c ) {


            $.ajax({
                url:'http://QUERYURL' + str +'EXAMPLE',

                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){

                    obj = {};
                    matches = [];

                    _.each( data.results, function(item){
                        matches.push( item.title );
                        obj[ item.title ] = "https:/"+item.url;
                    });

                    c(matches);
                }
            });
        },
        updater: function ( selectedName ) {

            url = obj[ selectedName ];
            window.open(url);
            return selectedName;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, the typeahead will only show you items that are in your source JSON which match the characters typed in.

i.e. if you typed `"g-"` I imagine it would only show you `"g-mail"` and not `"google"`

That is how this typeahead works.

You should retrieve all possible entries once and let the typeahead work with that source list instead of getting a subset each time perhaps?

Comment: ok that makes sense ... is there a easy way to display all results of the json? When i used the http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js i got displayed every result (but i get different problems so i switched to bootstrap)

Comment: I'm not really sure why you want to use a typeahead to show results which don't match what the user has typed, that's what they are made for.

Answer (score 0):

Use matcher.

The code would be like

```
matcher: function (item) {
                return true;
            }
```